# Slow scrolling with QTableView on other comp

Tags: c++, qt, optimization

I'm currently developping a database browsing app using Qt & C++. The databases are in our internal network.
I'm working & compiling on Win7 32 bits, with Qt 4.7.3 + qodbc driver.
My project goal is to make these data available for our ppl, even if they are travelling, using a VPN in that case.
The connection is very slow (I mean: VERY slow).

So, I have a QTableView which I populate with 2k results. I only need a win7 support, and it's working well on our company computers, which are in the network.
But on some computers things are really slow, ie scrolling on my QTableView. It seems to only happen while using the VPN. The way I use to populate my QTableView is just doing a setQuery()
So I'm wondering if there is some network stuff performed after the query is executed? If so, what can be the problem ?
I can't find any answer in Google nor in Qt doc.

EDIT: The problem seems to come directly from QSqlQuery. I've implemented the following model as a trial to avoid useless query (Yes, it's fast and dirty) :

```
class SqlAsyncModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
public:
  explicit SqlAsyncModel(QObject *parent = 0) : QSqlQueryModel(parent)  {}
  SqlAsyncModel(QSqlQueryModelPrivate &dd, QObject *parent)
              : QSqlQueryModel(dd, parent)      {}

  void    queryChange()       { _currRow = 0; qu = this->query(); qu.last(); }
  virtual QVariant    data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)
  {
      int r = index.row(); int c = index.column();
      if(!index.isValid() || role & ~Qt::DisplayRole || r < 0 || c < 0)
         return QVariant();
      while (_currRow < r)
         if (!nextValue())   goto ret;
      while (_currRow > r)
         if (prevValue())    goto ret;
  ret: return (qu.record().value(c));
  // Returns value or QVariant() if invalid QSqlRecord
  }
private:
  inline bool nextValue() { _currRow++; return qu.next(); }
  inline bool prevValue() { _currRow--; return qu.previous(); }
  int         _currRow;
  QSqlQuery   qu;
```

This still gives me the same behaviour.
Note: I also use:

```
while (mySqlAsyncModel->canFetchMore())
    mySqlAsyncModel->fetchMore();
```

Comment: Try running Wireshark on the problematic machine(s) and seeing what network traffic (if any) is being sent/received while the user is scrolling.  The results might be informative.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. After doing that, it has appear that my QTableView is refreshing the items at each scroll / appearance of the window, which is obviously the source of the problem.
It seems that there is no way in QTableView to set something like a timer for refresh. I go take a look at others widget...

Comment: I think the QTableView class is fine, but you may need to substitute in a different QAbstractTableModel subclass that suits your purpose better (instead the vanilla QSqlQueryModel object that you are probably using now).  This article might be of interest:  http://blog.wysota.eu.org/index.php/2006/12/26/remote-models/

Comment: Also this might be helpful:  http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9602

Comment: Interresting links. It makes me digging into MVC architecture, and I learned a lot of things I were not aware of. However it seems that it doesn't really suits my needs.
My query retrieve 256 results from the server by default (now I'm using fetchMore()). I get all the result (using fetchMore()) in 15 to 20 second, which is acceptable for my customer. But while scrolling, extra queries are performed, and that's the real problem.
An other issue, it's because of that behaviour (real time update), closing the connection to the DB leads to clear the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem comes from the QODBCResult behaviour.
I downloaded Qt's Sources, and edit odbc driver.
For those interrested in it, you need to change the behaviour of QODBCResult::data(int) and at least QODBCResult::fetch(int) (and maybe QODBCResult::fetchprevious/next/last/first if you really want something clean) functions.

I personnally add a QList buffer, where I store my rows when they are requested. It's almost the same behaviour as Qt (since it don't cache everything but only the requested rows). My app take up to 38-40 Mbs in memory for 22k rows / 55 columns of text and floats in cache.

Comment: So why hasn't this been fixed by now? Seems to me that a simple cache of requested rows should have been implemented by now since it's just a matter of quality of supplied artefacts. For example, I have a simple query loading 50 rows by 5 columns and every view linked to this model lags like hell. I should implement my own model and cache the data locally but for 50 rows why shouldn't I be able to use a standard model and be done with it and know at least that my users won't complain about slow performance with just 50 rows.

Comment: I guess that's a question you'll have to ask on the Qt forums / mailing list ;)

Comment: Seems like the views are the problem here. With a few debugging prints inserted into the model, I could see lots of calls to the `data` member function, every time the view is interacted with and for all indexes not just visible ones. Mainly it checks for new data for various roles. Caching the data locally in a fast data structure alleviates the lag but function calls are still made as often as before, they just take less to return. Further improvement should be made inside the views to implement virtualization.